# Why did Dumbledore accept Lupin's resignation?

Tags: harry-potter

After Sirius and Buckbeak's escape in *The Prisoner of Azkaban* Snape lets it slip accidentally on purpose that Lupin is a werewolf. Lupin,  fearing the parents reaction, offers his resignation, which Dumbledore accepts.

In a similar situation, when Hagrid was exposed as half-giant by the Daily Prophet's reporter, Rita Skeeter, Dumbledore behaved quite differently:

> Dumbledore stood up. “I refuse to accept your resignation,  Hagrid,
>   and I expect you back at work on Monday,” he said. “You  will join me
>   for breakfast at eight-thirty in the Great Hall. No excuses. Good
>   afternoon to you all.”  *~Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire- Rita Skeeter's Scoop*

Even before, when Draco Malfoy was injured during Hagrid's lesson and his father, Lucius made quite a fuss about his son's injury, Dumbledore stood by his decision to keep Hagrid as a teacher. At some point he also employed Firenze, a centaur, which probably also didn't met with 100% approval from the parents of the students and the more conservative Hogwarts Governors, not to mention the High Inquisitor of Hogwarts.

Disregarding pressure from prejudiced parents and ministry officials is completely in character for Dumbledore. He was always sympathetic of the situation of people who were derogatorily called 'halfbreeds' by bigots like Umbridge, so I was surprised he'd let go of an excellent DADA teacher who was also an Order member, and who probably saved Harry's life teaching him the patronus charm. There was this little slip of Professor Lupin turning into a werewolf and trying to eat Harry and Hermione, but things like these are really common at Hogwarts.
He also must have known what a miserable existence werewolves led outside of the school.

So, what could be a good
in-universe explaination why Dumbledore let go of such an excellent DADA teacher?

Comment: because a half-giant and a centaur are still rational. You can't reason with a werewolf! Also, if you are not familiar with it, I would suggest reading up on the curse that Voldemort put on the DADA position.

Comment: @skooba but wouldn't that mean that the curse was self-fulfilling?

Comment: @Skooba If it was possible to curse *position* then any half-decent Dark Lord would have positions for all his enemies.

Comment: @R.Skeeter It's a good question. Out of all the DADA teachers to fall victim to [Voldemort's jinx on the post](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Jinx_on_the_post_of_Defence_Against_the_Dark_Arts_teacher), this one felt the most like a copout to me. I mean, had Dumbledore refused the resignation, he'd be bypassing the jinx, which he knew about. Maybe the jinx causes a kind of bad luck until the teacher inevitably quits, and so, had Dumbledore refused, maybe Lupin would have died or some other situation to fulfill the jinx would present itself.

Comment: cos he had fleas

Comment: @R.Skeeter what curse? Was there actually a curse on the DADA position? I thought it was just a revolving door gag that the author put in to keep the cast fresh.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I don't know if you're joking or not, but there was actually a curse on the DADA position. In particular, Voldemort cursed that position when Dumbledore refused to hire him as a DADA teacher. This is explained in *Half-Blood Prince*.

Comment: @A.Darwin No, I'm serious. I never heard of this curse till now. I always thought it was just a series of really horrible coincidences. But wait though... Voldemort actually applied to work as a teacher at Hogwarts. That is surprising. O.O

Comment: @TheGreatDuck he applied twice, first to Armando Dippet who was Headmaster before Dumbledore (few years after graduating), and then to Dumbledore himself. Both of them refused, for different reasons. When Dumbledore refused, Voldemort cursed the position. Dumbledore also understood that Voldemort didn't really apply because he loved teaching... if you haven't read/watched the complete story, let's just say that he wanted to gain access to the Hogwarts castle much more than he wanted to teach. This is related to what happens in the last two books, and the last three movies.

Comment: @A.Darwin I've read all the books and seen all the movies. No need to hide spoilers. I just forgot that detail.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The point was Lupin was actually dangerous, and he himself did not feel safe around children anymore.

> ‘This time tomorrow, the owls will start arriving from parents –
>   they will not want a werewolf teaching their children, Harry. And
>   after last night, I see their point. I could have bitten any of you ...
>   that must never happen again.’
>
> ‘You’re the best Defence Against the Dark Arts teacher we’ve ever
>   had!’ said Harry. ‘Don’t go!’

Hagrid never hurt a student because he was a half giant, Hagrid was just a fairly poor teacher.

Lupin himself decided he could no longer be trusted around students, because he literally turned into a monster on campus, and could have bitten tons of students.

With Lupin's own firm rational decision to quit, it was only natural for Dumbledore to accept, even aside from the pressure students, the Hogwarts board, and the ministry would put on Dumbledore's back.

Comment: That makes sense. So Dumbledore agreed with him that Werewolves are actually dangerous and shant be kept near children even with the wolfsbane? That he made a mistake allowing Lupin to study at Hogwarts and later return as a teacher?

Comment: @R.Skeeter Lupin was, like all of the defense against the dark arts teachers, non-optimal candidates to begin with. having a secret werewolf taking his potion to keep him safe with no one the wiser is one thing, having lupin outed as a werewolf, AND forgetting his potion while on the job, Dumbledore would have had to fire him anyways. its like forgetting to take your seizer medicine, having a seizer while driving, and killing someone in a car accident. you still get in trouble even though you cant control it.

Comment: Makes sense, even if it was a bleak day for the supporters of werewolf rights.

Comment: @R.Skeeter we also know umbridge later passes a piece of legislation that makes it almost impossible for lupin to get a job anyway.

Comment: It seems you agree with her on this :-)

Comment: Malfoy was injured in Hagrid's classes. While that's not the same thing as Hagrid hurting a student, it could be blamed somewhat on his teaching style.

Comment: @sumelic right, his teaching style was at fault, not the fact hes a half giant, thats the distinction i was trying to make.

Comment: "fairly poor teacher" seems good enough reason to me. Don't fire the guy... he's an excellent game keeper... but it would seem wiser to have someone competent teaching the courses if at all possible.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Hagrid was a long time friend of Dumbledore and had been there for many years. There were good reasons not to fire him, such as longevity. With a werewolf (and their first year on the job) it would be incredibly difficult to find good reason to keep them around. Plus, with a bad teacher one can just tell him to be more careful. With a werewolf there is a constant liability. One bite, and students would have a lifelong debilitating illness. Not to be discriminatory, but I doubt anyone *wants* to be forced into becoming a werewolf! Plus, people could die. Malfoy merely broke a bone

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Plus, Malfoy was continuously reckless around wild animals during that class. He would always assume that he could just stroll up to some beast and command it to roll over and lick his hand and it would obey. If anything, Malfoy should be the one in trouble for that situation, not Hagrid. Malfoy is old enough to understand basic safety procedures and listen when told not to approach a dangerous animal a certain way. Hagrid can only do so much. The classes have a certain curriculum, I'd imagine, so Malfoy would've seen a beast of that species one way or another and get hurt.

Answer (score 25):

**The curse on the job; this was likely a mercy towards Lupin.**

There's a curse on the DADA job which means a single person can't hold it for more than a year, and after many years of cycling through teachers, I think Dumbledore is well-inclined to believe the curse does exist.

The outcome for a lot of DADA teachers isn't pretty: in the last two years, one was possessed and then died, another suffered severe memory loss. Moody and Umbridge don't fare much better. Being able to resign without severe bodily injury is actually doing pretty well, as DADA staff go.

Unlike the Ministry, Dumbledore hasn't had much success standing up to the curse (or he hasn't been trying). If Lupin doesn't resign now, he'll probably be gone by the end of the year anyway, but in potentially much messier circumstances. It's kinder to let him go than risk further injury.

(Given the blood lust at the Ministry, one very plausible outcome is that Lupin is accused of attacking a student while a werewolf, then executed and/or consigned to Azkaban. Neither are preferable to a quiet resignation, particularly if Dumbledore is starting to think about who he might want in a revived Order of the Phoenix.)

Comment: +1 Yes, the curse is very intriguing. Dumbledore never specifically says it exists, btw, only that he wasn't able to keep a DADA teacher since he refused Voldy the job. Doesn't look like he tried much, tho. Lockhart he hired with the intention to expose, Snape he asked to do a job after which he'd be presumably on the run and Moody was never asked to return.

Comment: @R.Skeeter "Lockhart he hired with the intention to expose" source? The only thing I recall the books saying is that Lockhart was the only candidate.

Comment: @Salmononius2 found it.  there was this answer to the question *why did D hire Lockhart?* my phone's acting up so i cannot link it, but it's easy to find. Also there's that line D drops "Impaled on your own sword, Gilderoy" after Lockharts memory gets wiped, meaning he was well aware L was a fraud. So it's probable, but youre right of it not being canon.

Answer (score 19):

The character of Lupin is a very interesting one. The treatment and discrimination he faces from the wider wizarding world has (quite understandably) corroded his spirit. He allows himself to be overcome by a certain amount of self-loathing and self-pity. And I make absolutely no judgement about that, I actually think this makes Lupin one of the most interesting characters. I'm not saying whether it's right or wrong, or acceptable or unacceptable, or whether you and I could do any better, but it leads him to a number of self-destructive behaviours.

The most notable of these is the way he behaves towards his wife and child.

He does not initially want to "inflict himself" (my words) upon Nymphadora Tonks:

> 'And I've told *you* a million times,' said Lupin, refusing to meet her eyes, staring at the floor, 'that I am too old for you, too poor ... too dangerous ...'
>
> 'I've said all along you're taking a ridiculous line on this, Remus,' said Mrs Weasley over Fleur's shoulder as she patted her on the back.
>
> 'I am not being ridiculous,' said Lupin steadily. 'Tonks deserves somebody young and whole.'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.582 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 29, *The Phoenix Lament*

Then:

> 'Don't you understand what I've done to my wife and my unborn child? I should never have married her, I've made her an outcast!'
>
> Lupin kicked aside the chair he had overturned.
>
> 'You have only ever seen me amongst the Order, or under Dumbledore's protection at Hogwarts! You don't know how most of the wizarding world sees creatures like me! When they know of my affliction, they can barely talk to me! Don't you see what I've done? Even her own family is disgusted by our marriage, what parents want their only daughter to marry a werewolf? And the child - the child -'
>
> Lupin actually seized handfuls of his own hair; he looked quite deranged.
>
> 'My kind don't usually breed! It will be like me, I am convinced of it - how can I forgive myself, when I knowingly risked passing on my own condition to an innocent child? And if, by some miracle, it is not like me, then it will be better off, a hundred times so, without a father of whom it must always be ashamed!'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - pp.175-6 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 11, *The Bribe*

In this extract we see, further, how he feels about himself, his condition and his decision to have a child.

And so he walks out on them.

Even when he is with Tonks, he is not open with her, he hides himself from her, and envelops himself in remorse for having married her and in misery at the discrimination he suffers:

> Although Lupin smiled as he shook Harry's hand, Harry thought he looked rather unhappy. It was all very odd; Tonks, beside him, looked simply radiant.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.101 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 7, *The Will of Albus Dumbledore*

Again:

> 'Sorry about last night,' she added in a whisper, as Harry led them up the aisle. 'The Ministry's being very anti-werewolf at the moment and we thought our presence might not do you any favours.'
>
> 'It's fine, I understand,' said Harry, speaking more to Lupin than Tonks. Lupin gave him a swift smile, but as they turned away, Harry saw Lupin's face fall again into lines of misery. He did not understand it, but there was no time to dwell on the matter: Hagrid was causing a certain amount of disruption.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - p.116 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 8, *The Wedding*

How much you blame him is up to you, I find the character of Lupin really really interesting. And this all speaks to one of the darker, more insidious results of discrimination and what it can give those who suffer it to do, how it can destroy their lives - by, sadly, negatively affecting their actions. This can have a horrible effect on those close to them, as we see here, because suffering discrimination can cause people to act very badly.

Nevertheless, I think the example of Remus Lupin is an exquisite warning to us all about just what will help us and what will harm us. And, again, a bad action is a bad action, however malignant your circumstances. It was Remus Lupin who directed his own legs out of the door.

But the point here is that Dumbledore knows this about Remus Lupin. He is much too wise to try to persuade Lupin out of this mindset.

> 'Goodbye, then, Remus,' said Dumbledore soberly. Lupin shifted the Grindylow tank slightly so that he and Dumbledore could shake hands. Then, with a final nod to Harry, and a swift smile, Lupin left the office.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* - p.310 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 22, *Owl Post Again*

He is resigned.

It is true, I suppose, that Dumbledore could bewitch, or hoodwink Lupin into staying, but he cannot exorcise Lupin's demons. He can make Lupin stay, he cannot make Lupin want to stay.

Comment: Good answer, except a 17 year old Harry suceeded where the master manipulator didn't even try. After all Harry's shock treatment returned Lupin to his senses. And dumbledore can be ruthless for good reasons too. How he said to the grieving severus: 'remember lily's eyes'? And made Harry feel ashamed for not trying any harder in book6, controlling Harry's trial in OotP... i am sure he could've played on L's sense of duty.

Comment: @R.Skeeter Leaving a teaching post is not like leaving your wife and child, I brought that up to establish my views about Lupin, his mindset, and his character. That's who he is, Dumbledore knows that, and he knows Lupin won't be persuaded back into teaching as the owls calling for his resignation descend on Hogwarts school. This was be an unkindness to Lupin, and frankly not that vital. I know Dumbledore struggles with DADA teachers, but he could not have foreseen what the need to hire Moody would do, he doesn't need Lupin to teach like Lupin's family need him

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't letting him go would add another defeat to his already miserable life, which'll make him even more angsty? L is an exceptionally good teacher, D could've scolded him for forgetting his wolfsbane, doped him up on Felix Felucius just in case and convinced him to stay. But maybe you're right and D respected his decision and that was it.

Comment: @R.Skeeter No. Trying and failing to shackle him to a job he wants to leave is not going to help him. It was over the moment Snape spilt the beans, possibly even before then, the moment he began to transform. That was the defeat. Lupin can't bear to face the storm of owls and he can't live with the possibility that he might bite someone. He needs to get out, and he will, Dumbledore doesn't want to cause him any more pain by delaying his obvious instinct to flee and possibly burning a bridge into the bargain. He was a good and well-liked teacher, he wasn't a linchpin.

Comment: You want it to have been the wrong decision for Lupin to leave. I don't think it was, but it doesn't matter, that wasn't the question. In my opinion the answer to the question is Lupin was a broken man, look at the way he behaves in his relationship, he doesn't have the fight. Dumbledore knows it, and he knows nailing Lupin down would destroy him

Comment: Ahh. That's might be the case.

Answer (score 12):

Hagrid believe *other* people want him gone — he is *reluctantly* tending his resignation under the misbelief that he is unwanted. Dumbledore's show of support by refusing the resignation is greatly wanted and appreciated!

Lupin wants *himself* gone — in light of his recent experiences, he fully believes he should not be in the position he holds. Lupin would likely resent Dumbledore refusing to let him go.

Answer (score 3):

Hagrid's resignation was a spur of the moment emotional reaction to a difficult situation and Dumbledore knew him well enough to know that he would be able to ride it out with some support and effectively just prevented him from making a hasty decision.

Also Hagrid had lived at Hogwarts for almost his entire life and you have to question how he would cope if he left. By contrast Lupin has only had his job for less than a year and while he probably appreciated the work he was just as much doing Dumbledore a favour by exposing  himself to so much public scrutiny and they probably both realised that it was a bit of a gamble (even without taking the probable curse in the job into account).

So Lupin's resignation was rather more measured and considered decision and happened at the end of the year so Dumbledore had little choice but to accept it.

We could also speculate that Dumbledore specifically wanted Lupin to teach Harry for at least one year as part of his preparation for eventually facing Voldemort and possibly also to create a link between the original order of the Phoenix and the  current generation of Hogwarts students.

It is also worth considering that if we accept that the DADA post really was cursed then this is actually a very serious handicap to Dumbledore in educating his students about the coming threat. This may also explain why he employed such obviously dire teachers as Lockheart and Quirrell as they were expendable placeholders and he saved his closest allies untill Harry was ready to take the best advantage from their teaching.

Indeed he may have accepted Umbridge because he wasn't too bothered that she would fall foul of the curse and being really cynical that dealing with her would in itself be an important lesson in itself for Harry and his fellow students, an idea which is born out by the fact that here appointment lead to the formation of the DA which probably helped the fight against Voldemort more than a moderately competent DADA teacher would have done. This also suggests that Dumbledore really did feel that he was training soldiers as much as educating children.

Answer (score 0):

## Lupin failed to disclose that Black was an unregistered animagus at a time when Black was believed to pose a credible threat to the safety of Hogwarts

There is another "red flag" on Lupin -- his **failure to disclose that Sirius Black was an unregistered animagus** at a time when...

- ...he had a good-faith belief that Black were guilty of the crime for which he had been incarcerated; **and**
- ...following the attack on the Fat Lady, it was evident that Black intended to penetrate the defences of Hogwarts and had credible prospects of succeeding (indeed, Black did make it into Harry's dormitory on a subsequent attempt).

Lupin disclosed details of the unregistered animagi (Black, Pettigrew, and J. Potter) to Dumbledore the morning after his uncontrolled transformation. Lupin's complicity in this breach of wizarding law is probably criminal conduct (assuming that the age of criminal responsibility in the wizarding Britain is before the age of majority, as it is in Muggle Britain), which would have disqualified him from a teaching job had it been known (assuming that wizarding Britain had an equivalent to Muggle DBS checks). More seriously, given the circumstances enumerated above, Lupin's failure to disclose such information earlier was a serious error of judgement that (if Black had been a murderer) could have cost lives (i.e.: at a time when one of the unregistered animagi was at large and believed to pose a serious threat to life, the animagus offences were not merely 'historical').